# How does one put the ssh-agent socket file in a directory other than /tmp

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent

I'd like to put the socket file that ssh-agent creates in a directory other than /tmp. If you look at the man page it mentions $TMPDIR so one might conclude that setting that environment variable will allow for this. I tried these:

```
$ export TMPDIR=$HOME/.ssh
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-gZSxgCXIOMVK/agent.4287; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=4288; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 4288;
```

and

```
$ TMPDIR=$HOME/.ssh ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-cv6U38tey4XQ/agent.5160; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=5161; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 5161;
```

As you can see, ssh-agent ignores TMPDIR and puts the socket file in /tmp.

I looked at (I cloned it then ran grep) the ssh-agent source (git@github.com:openssh/openssh-portable.git) and searched for TMPDIR. I had one hit in the function mktemp_proto (misc.c:1401). It looks for the TMPDIR environment variable and uses it if defined, otherwise uses /tmp. The caller of mktemp looks like it calls, then creates the socket's directory, and later creates the socket file. This looks OK.

My next thought was that the version I am using is older than when this feature was added. Looking at the github repo mentioned above I determined that this was added in Version 5.8 on 2011/01/12. Running strings on the executable

```
$ cat /usr/bin/ssh-agent | strings | grep OpenSSH
```

outputs several lines, including this one

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

So, the executable is at least 6.6.1. Doing a similar grep on TMPDIR finds one hit. So, this executable should be using TMPDIR.

I did this all on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

So my question is: How can I get ssh-agent to create a socket file in a directory of my choosing?

Comment: `TMPDIR=$HOME/.ssh ssh-agent` This works as expected for me, albeit using a much newer version of ssh.